# How can I create a view with widgets inside my app Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

i am currently trying to learn how to make widgets. I added widget extension to my app, and xcode gave me some basics widgets for example. The question is, i want to let user see my widgets not only on home screen, but also inside the app, on some custom view. How can i do it? I am new to SwiftUI so any help will be appreciated)[![enter image description here][1]][1]

P.s this is what i am trying to do, but only in my app)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbnlQ.png

Comment: Widgets are basically just SwiftUI views - You can share code between your widget extension and your app. You can't use the WidgetKit specific background views in your main app.

Comment: Sorry for dumb question, but how to do so? i mean how to share a code of widget? if its possible can you show an example? Thanks a lot

Comment: In Xcode you will have two targets; your app and the widget extension. Click on the source file that you want to share and in the file navigator on the right you can select the targets. Select both targets. You can. Now use that view in both targets

Comment: You will also need to share appropriate data model files in both targets so that the views have something to display

Comment: I provided the answer but someone vote it negative so I deleted that.

Comment: I tried it, added two targets in widget files, but now, when i am trying to use widgetView in my app xcode complains (   reference to invalid associated type 'Entry' of type 'Provider') Must mention, after adding widget extension, i didnt change anything there

Comment: Look at the “preview” code at the bottom of the widget sample. You can mimic that.

Comment: Widgets need a `Entry` which comes from your `Provider`.  You won't have those classes in your full app.  You will need to design your solution so that your `Entry` wraps some other model object.  You can use that model in your views.   In your Widget extension you will need some supplemental "wrapper" views that accept your `Entry`, access it model object that it contains and passes that to the actual view.  That way your rendering is abstracted from the WidgetKit mechanics

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reflect real time changes to your widgets from inside your application, you need to share those changes between widget and application. To do so, you can use `@AppStorage` property wrapper.

```
@AppStorage("fontColor", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.authorName.myAppName.shared")) var fontColor: Color = Color.white
```

Also, go to your app target in Xcode, click on `Signing & Capabilities`, and click on `+ Capability` on top left. Add New `App Group` with the same name i.e `group.com.authorName.myAppName.shared`.
Do the same for your widget extension target too.

Now when you are working on widget view inside your app ,if you have any text inside that view, assign that `fontColor`  property to it.

Last step, when you are enter background, then you have to reload all widget timelines. For that, inside sceneDelegate, you can handle it like following:

```
func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
}
```

That way, you'll be able to see real time changes to your widget that you have performed inside your app.
Hope it helps.